# c++ beginner errors, homework

Tags: c++

I keep getting these 2 errors in my code

> ```
> In function 'int main()':
> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int'
> error: in passing argument 1 of 'void swapInt(int&, int&)'
> ```

but the real problem I'm having is with swapInt. I need to take in 2 ints
and then switch their values with their parameters so what was once a is now b
and what was once b is now a. please help!

```
void swapInt (int &a, int &b);

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    swapInt(1, 2);
    cout << a << " " << b;

    return 0;
}

void swapInt (int &a, int &b) {
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    //cout << a << " " << b;
}
```

Comment: You declare the variables `a` and `b` but then you don't use them. You are passing literals into the function (1 and 2) instead of references to the integers where they are stored. Try setting `a=1` and `b=2` in the beginning of `main()`, and then call `swapInt(a,b)`.

Comment: You have to understand that the `a` you define in `main` has nothing to do with the `a` in `swapInt`... the concept behind that is called "variable scope".

Comment: Be careful. Swapping 1 and 2 will stretch the fabric of spacetime considerably, what with all the formulas like 1+1=2 that will become 2+2=1! You don't want to play such games with the Universe!

Comment: Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment. Pick and use an established [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/indent_style) to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function works with the address of variables, but you're passing in number constants. You need to pass in the variables like:

```
void swapInt (int &a, int &b);

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    swapInt(a, b);
    cout << a << " " << b;

    return 0;
}

void swapInt (int &a, int &b) {
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    //cout << a << " " << b;
}
```

Comment: well the assignment says: swapInt The third function is one called swapInt that takes two int parameters. It does not return anything. The purpose of this function is to swap the values of the two parameters. That is, if swapInt is called with one variable with a value of 5 and another with a value of 10, after the function call ends, the first variable will now have a value of 10 and the second, 5.You will need a local variable in the function to store one of the values while the swapping occurs.  So What should I do if I have to be able to call them

Comment: @user1290726, What I posted will do exactly what the assignment is asking for. I don't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: @user: Think of it this way: You have two boxes A and B, both containing objects 1 and 2 respectively. You then give both boxes to someone (say, swapInt) and ask them to switch the objects in the two boxes, so now box A has object 2 and box B has object 1. This is what your `swapInt` function does. If you decide to give swapInt object 1 and object 2 and ask it to swap the objects in the two boxes, it won't know what to do because there's only two objects and no boxes, and that's what your compiler is complaining about. Your variables `a` and `b` are these "boxes", both containing integer `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the function as "pass-by-reference" thus it expects a variable when you are calling the function.

You can't pass an integer value to functions that take parameters by reference.